# expo.Google.logInAsync makes my app crash

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I'm using an expo application

with these packages installed :
react-navigation and react-native-calendar.

recently I've updated the expo-cli and SDK to 32
in Genymotion emulator everything works great,

but in my phone (MI MIX) after the google login modal appears and i login

the app crashes.

the code for the login is as follwed:

```
import { Google } from 'expo';

in the componentDidMount:

 const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: 'someclientid',
        iosClientId: 'someclientid',
        scopes: ['profile', 'email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
      });
```

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.172.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

any clue whata am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
it seems like it works on other android devices

Comment: did you find any solution ?